# wordpress create two text field plugin save them in database

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i want to create plugin for WordPress that save two text field's information in database.
is there any possible way to save data in database without creating new table.

Comment: Post Meta is one way to do it. [Setting options ](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option) is another way. Have you done any research on the subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress has API for you to do this.

[See what is prepared for you](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API)

[Example to copy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages#See_It_All_Together)